# How can I display, using Java, my databases?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm programming a Java utility to make security copies of all my databases in my PC. I know how to program the time and I know to work with tables, but no to list all my DB in my program using a JList or a JTable.

How could I do it?

Thanks all!

Comment: Can you be more specific? What database? And in case you use a jdbc, you just summed up all the components to reach the goal you want. So give your code, that does not work, and we can help you. This is not the place to state an open assignment to programmers. So try yourselve, and in case it fails, ask. (with the code and the error)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what DB? most db has jdbc connections (google for open source solutions, the db name and jdbc). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity

And with jdbc connections you can always create your own data structure from the queries... and put it in a jtable.

Another tip (but if you want to make a generic solution with nice interfcae): Have a look at swingx and jxtables? have some nice features...

https://java.net/projects/swingx/

they have some nice interfaces for databases, to connect and than show them in tables (and open source):

https://java.net/projects/databinding/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/java/org/jdesktop/dataset/DataConnection.java?rev=421

As Andreas states, using the default jdbc classes and functions will help. most open source jdbc has nice descriptions.

Some tips of unknown but very nice jdbc connections:

- csv jdbc (has a lot of unit tests with examoples in it hoiw to get
  table data and meta info): http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/ or the code in git: https://sourceforge.net/projects/csvjdbc/ see the test to see how things work. e.g. test metadata to see how things work: https://sourceforge.net/p/csvjdbc/code/ci/master/tree/src/test/java/org/relique/jdbc/csv/TestCsvDriver.java
- h2 db http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html see this metadata overview: http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcDatabaseMetaData.html

They have both nice examples and tests (csv jdbc) to show how it works (just google), same counts for other type of jdbc connections

You can find the code in above, but as requested in the remark, here an example of how to get the table names from the h2 db (most jdbc work the same):

```
public ArrayList<String> getTableNames(boolean withSystemTables)
            throws SQLException {
        // Note: system table are tables like Catalogue
        ArrayList<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();
        DatabaseMetaData metadata = getMetaData();
        String tableNamePattern = null;
        String catalog = null;
        String schemaPattern = null;
        String[] types = { "TABLE" };
        if (withSystemTables) {
            types = null;
        }
        ResultSet rs = metadata.getTables(catalog, schemaPattern,
                tableNamePattern, types);
        if (rs == null) {
            return tables;
        }
        boolean debugFunction=false;
        while (rs.next()) {
            String table = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
            tables.add(table);
            if (debugFunction){
                String tableType=rs.getString("TABLE_TYPE");
                String msg=table+" : "+tableType;
                //System.out.println(msg);
                log.fine(msg);
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        return tables;

    }
```

Note: the code above can be shorter, I splitted things out for readability and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

To query the database schema in a database agnostic way, call [`Connection.getMetaData()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData%28%29) to get a [`DatabaseMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) object, then use the various methods, such as:

- [`getCatalogs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getCatalogs%28%29)
- [`getSchemas(String catalog, String schemaPattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getSchemas%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [`getTables(String catalog, String schemaPattern, String tableNamePattern, String[] types)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29)
- [`getColumns(String catalog, String schemaPattern, String tableNamePattern, String columnNamePattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thank you all! But your answers are about to show tables or information. But I want to display each name of each database to select a database, not a table.

Comment: @lordmiaux For MySQL, I believe `getCatalogs()` will list the databases of the server you're connected to.